# JOLT JSON Conversion is not working as expected

Tags: java, arrays, json, transformation, jolt

I was trying to convert the json from one JSON Format to another JSON Format using JOLT, But i'm not able to get the expected output. I have included the my work around below.  Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

My input.json

```
{
    "Result": {
    },
    "Content": [
        {
            "MovieDetails": [
                {
                    "Key": "TicketNumber",
                    "Value": "DF-0001"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "MovieName",
                    "Value": "Test"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "MovieDetails": [
                {
                    "Key": "TicketNumber",
                    "Value": "DF-0002"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "MovieName",
                    "Value": "Test2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "MovieDetails": [
                {
                    "Key": "TicketNumber",
                    "Value": "DF-0003"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "MovieName",
                    "Value": "Test3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My Expected Output.json

```
{
"Result": {

},
"Content": [
    {
        "MovieDetails": {
            "TicketNumber": "DF-0001",
            "MovieName": "Test1"
        },
        "MovieDetails": {
            "TicketNumber": "DF-0002",
            "MovieName": "Test2"
        }.
        "MovieDetails": {
            "TicketNumber": "DF-0003",
            "MovieName": "Test3"
        }
    }
]
}
```

My Actual Output.json

```
{
"Result": {

},
"Content": [
    {
        "MovieDetails": {
            "TicketNumber": ["DF-0001","DF-0002","DF-0003"],
            "MovieName": ["Test1","Test2","Test3"]
        }
    }
]
}
```

My Spec.json

```
[
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "Result": {
                "*": "Result.&"
            },
            "Content": {
                "*": {
                    "MovieDetails": {
                        "*": {
                            "Value": "Content.MovieDetails.@(1,Key)"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked with below spec...

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Result": "Result",
      "Content": {
        "*": {
          "MovieDetails": {
            "*": {
              "Value": "Content[&3].MovieDetails.@(1,Key)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```